# Installing JDBC on java 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, ide, libraries

I need to update a program from Java 8 to Java 11 for the upcoming EOL, the program has moved over with no issue. The issue is that it relies on the JDBC driver that was originally placed inside the JRE folder. Java 11 does not have this folder so how do you install it?

I am using the IntelliJ community edition IDE, and using AdoptOpenJDK-11. I am attempting to connect to a MySQL database(8.0.20 CommunityServer) and trying to use Connector/J 8.0.20 from  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: It would help a lot more if you tell us which Database and JDBC you're talking about...

Comment: Added more information about the database and JDBC

Comment: You should never have placed JDBC drivers in the JRE folder in the first place; that was always a bad practice anyway. You should put it on the classpath of your application, just like any other library you use. Exactly how that needs to be done depends on the application or its build tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add it manually and this depends of your database, you have two ways:

1. If you are using [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) or gradle, then add the dependency in the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`
2. If you are use the old way(which is not recommended) then add the jdbc jar in the lib folder.

Fore more details read this: [Oracle JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html#01_01)

Comment: I've marked this as my answer, turns out my issue was instead tot do with instead how I was calling the driver that caused it to not recognize it, but this could be useful to others.